# Use pattern to collect terms in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

With Mathematica I would like collect terms `from (1 + a + x + y)^4` according to the exponents of `x` and `y`, so

```
(1 + a + x + y)^4 = (...)x^0 y^0 + (...)x^1 y^0 + (...)x^0 y^1 + ...
```

The [Mathematica help](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Collect.html?q=Collect&lang=en) has a nice example which I tried to imitate:

```
D[f[Sqrt[ x^2 + 1 ]], {x, 3}]
Collect[%, Derivative[ _ ][ f ][ _ ], Together]
```

This collects derivative terms of the same order (and the same argument for f)

Can anyone explain why the following imitation does not work?

```
Collect[(1 + a + x + y)^4, x^_ y^_]
```

gives

```
(1 + a + x + y)^4
```

Any suggestions for a solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per [Sasha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627365/use-pattern-to-collect-terms-in-mathematica/6627536#6627536), you have to [`Expand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Expand.html?q=Expand&lang=en) the polynomial to use [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Collect.html?q=Collect&lang=en). However, even then it isn't that simple of a problem. Using `Collect` you can group by two variables, but it depends on how you order them:

```
In[1]:= Collect[ (1 + a + x + y)^4 // Expand, {x, y}]
Out[1]:= 1 + 4 a + 6 a^2 + 4 a^3 + a^4 + x^4 + 
         (4 + 12 a + 12 a^2 + 4 a^3) y + (6 + 12 a + 6 a^2) y^2 + 
         (4 + 4 a) y^3 + y^4 + x^3 (4 + 4 a + 4 y) + 
         x^2 (6 + 12 a + 6 a^2 + (12 + 12 a) y + 6 y^2) + 
         x (4 + 12 a + 12 a^2 + 4 a^3 + (12 + 24 a + 12 a^2) y + 
         (12 + 12 a) y^2 + 4 y^3)
```

which pulls out any common factor of `x` resulting in coefficients that are polynomials in `y`.  If you used `{y,x}` instead, `Collect` would pull out the common factors of `y` and you'd have polynomials in `x`.

Alternatively, you could supply a pattern, `x^_ y^_` instead of `{x,y}`, but at least in v.7, this does not collect anything.  The issue is that the pattern `x^_ y^_` requires an exponent to be present, but in terms like `x y^2` and `x^2 y` the exponent is implicit in at least one of the variables. Instead, we need to specify that a [default](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Default.html?q=Default&lang=en) value is acceptable, i.e. use `x^_. y^_.` which gives

```
Out[2]:= 1 + 4 a + 6 a^2 + 4 a^3 + a^4 + 4 x + 12 a x + 12 a^2 x + 4 a^3 x + 
         6 x^2 + 12 a x^2 + 6 a^2 x^2 + 4 x^3 + 4 a x^3 + x^4 + 4 y + 
         12 a y + 12 a^2 y + 4 a^3 y + (12 + 24 a + 12 a^2) x y + 
         (12 + 12 a) x^2 y + 4 x^3 y + 6 y^2 + 12 a y^2 + 6 a^2 y^2 + 
         (12 + 12 a) x y^2 + 6 x^2 y^2 + 4 y^3 + 4 a y^3 + 4 x y^3 + y^4
```

But, this only collects terms where both variables are present.  Truthfully, I can't seem to come up with a pattern that would make `Collect` function like you want, but I have found an alternative.

I'd use [`CoefficientRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoefficientRules.html?q=CoefficientRules&lang=en) instead, although it does require a little post-processing to put the result back into polynomial form. Using your polynomial, you get

```
In[3]:= CoefficientRules[(1 + a + x + y)^4, {x, y}]
Out[3]:= {{4, 0} -> 1, {3, 1} -> 4, {3, 0} -> 4 + 4 a, {2, 2} -> 6, 
          {2, 1} -> 12 + 12 a, {2, 0} -> 6 + 12 a + 6 a^2, {1, 3} -> 4, 
          {1, 2} -> 12 + 12 a, {1, 1} -> 12 + 24 a + 12 a^2, 
          {1, 0} -> 4 + 12 a + 12 a^2 + 4 a^3, {0, 4} -> 1, {0, 3} -> 4 + 4 a, 
          {0, 2} -> 6 + 12 a + 6 a^2, {0, 1} -> 4 + 12 a + 12 a^2 + 4 a^3, 
          {0, 0} -> 1 + 4 a + 6 a^2 + 4 a^3 + a^4}
```

Now, if you're only interested in the coefficients themselves, then you're done.  But, to transform this back into a polynomial, I'd use

```
In[4]:= Plus @@ (Out[3] /. Rule[{a_, b_}, c_] :> x^a y^b c)
Out[4]:= 1 + 4 a + 6 a^2 + 4 a^3 + a^4 + 
         (4 + 12 a + 12 a^2 + 4 a^3) x + 
         (6 + 12 a + 6 a^2) x^2 + (4 + 4 a) x^3 + x^4 + 
         (4 + 12 a + 12 a^2 + 4 a^3) y + (12 + 24 a + 12 a^2) x y + 
         (12 + 12 a) x^2 y + 4 x^3 y + (6 + 12 a + 6 a^2) y^2 + 
         (12 + 12 a) x y^2 + 6 x^2 y^2 + (4 + 4 a) y^3 + 
         4 x y^3 + y^4
```

**Edit**: After thinking about it, there is one more simplification that can be done. Since the coefficients are polynomials in `a`, they may be factorable. So, instead of using what `CoefficientRules` gives directly, we use `Factor` to simplify:

```
In[5]:=  Plus @@ (Out[3] /. Rule[{a_, b_}, c_] :> x^a y^b Factor[c])
Out[5]:= (1 + a)^4 + 4 (1 + a)^3 x + 6 (1 + a)^2 x^2 + 4 (1 + a) x^3 + x^4 + 
         4 (1 + a)^3 y + 12 (1 + a)^2 x y + 12 (1 + a) x^2 y + 4 x^3 y + 
         6 (1 + a)^2 y^2 + 12 (1 + a) x y^2 + 6 x^2 y^2 + 4 (1 + a) y^3 + 
         4 x y^3 + y^4
```

As can be seen, the coefficients are considerably simplified by using `Factor`, and this result could have been anticipated by thinking of `(1 + a + x + y)^4` as a simple trinomial with variables `(1 + a)`, `x`, and `y`.  With that in mind and replacing `1+a` with `z`, `CoefficientRules` then gives:

```
In[6]:= CoefficientRules[(z + x + y)^4, {x, y, z}]
Out[6]:= {{4, 0, 0} -> 1, {3, 1, 0} -> 4, {3, 0, 1} -> 4, 
          {2, 2, 0} -> 6, {2, 1, 1} -> 12, {2, 0, 2} -> 6, 
          {1, 3, 0} -> 4, {1, 2, 1} -> 12, {1, 1, 2} -> 12, 
          {1, 0, 3} -> 4, {0, 4, 0} -> 1, {0, 3, 1} -> 4, 
          {0, 2, 2} -> 6, {0, 1, 3} -> 4, {0, 0, 4} -> 1}
```

Or, in polynomial form

```
Out[7]:= x^4 + 4 x^3 y + 6 x^2 y^2 + 4 x y^3 + y^4 + 4 x^3 z + 
         12 x^2 y z + 12 x y^2 z + 4 y^3 z + 6 x^2 z^2 + 12 x y z^2 + 
         6 y^2 z^2 + 4 x z^3 + 4 y z^3 + z^4
```

which when you replace `z` with `(1 + a)` gives the identical result shown in `Out[5]`.

Answer (score 5):

`Collect` is a structural operation, so you need to expand first.

```
Collect[(1 + a + x + y)^4 // Expand, x^_ y^_]
```

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
In[1]:= Collect[(1 + a + x + y)^4 // Expand, {x^_ y^_, x^_ y, x y^_, x y, x, y}]

Out[1]= 1 + 4 a + 6 a^2 + 
 4 a^3 + a^4 + (4 + 12 a + 12 a^2 + 4 a^3) x + (6 + 12 a + 6 a^2) x^2 + (4 + 
    4 a) x^3 + x^4 + (4 + 12 a + 12 a^2 + 4 a^3) y + (12 + 24 a + 
    12 a^2) x y + (12 + 12 a) x^2 y + 
 4 x^3 y + (6 + 12 a + 6 a^2) y^2 + (12 + 12 a) x y^2 + 
 6 x^2 y^2 + (4 + 4 a) y^3 + 4 x y^3 + y^4
```

Alternatively you can use `Default` as suggested by [rcollyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198315/rcollyer):

```
In[2]:= Collect[(1 + a + x + y)^4 // Expand, {x^_. y^_., x, y}]

Out[2]= 1 + 4 a + 6 a^2 + 
 4 a^3 + a^4 + (4 + 12 a + 12 a^2 + 4 a^3) x + (6 + 12 a + 6 a^2) x^2 + (4 + 
    4 a) x^3 + x^4 + (4 + 12 a + 12 a^2 + 4 a^3) y + (12 + 24 a + 
    12 a^2) x y + (12 + 12 a) x^2 y + 
 4 x^3 y + (6 + 12 a + 6 a^2) y^2 + (12 + 12 a) x y^2 + 
 6 x^2 y^2 + (4 + 4 a) y^3 + 4 x y^3 + y^4
```

Answer (score 2):

Plus @@ MonomialList[(1 + a + x + y)^4, {x, y}]

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you were looking for

```
In[1]:= TraditionalForm[Collect[(1 + a + x + y)^4 // Expand, {x, y}], 
         ParameterVariables :> {a}]

Out[1]:= x^4+x^3 (4 y+4 a+4)+x^2 (6 y^2+(12 a+12) y+6 a^2+12 a+6)+
         x (4 y^3+(12 a+12) y^2+ (12 a^2+24 a+12) y+4 a^3+12 a^2+12 a+4)+
         y^4+(4 a+4) y^3+(6 a^2+12 a+6) y^2+(4 a^3+12 a^2+12 a+4) y+
         a^4+4 a^3+6 a^2+4 a+1
```